# new installation and lost windows 10 HD

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, system-installation

I did an install of Ubuntu 16 on a second SSD hard drive.  When I installed it I set up the partitions for the installation myself.  After installation my computer booted into the BIOS which I thought was weird.

I exited the BIOS and it went to "loading operating system" and just stayed there.  I can manually boot from my Ubuntu drive by pushing F12 and  can see my Windows drive in `gparted` but it shows the whole drive to be unallocated.  Also in my BIOS the Windows drive is not showing as a bootable device.

I had a similar installation before and everything worked fine and could boot into either OS through the grub menu.  The only thing I did differently this time is set up the Ubuntu partitions myself.  Not sure where I need to start to recover the Windows disk and be able to boot into it again.  I'm pretty sure all the info is still there I just cant access it.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: You still must turn off Windows fast start up which is hibernation. The Linux NTFS driver will not mount a hibernated NTFS. Also if NTFS needs chkdsk it will not mount it. Did you partition with gpt and install in UEFI boot mode? Is Secure boot off. How you boot UEFI or BIOS mode for install media is how it installs. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Boot-Repair Report will show details:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Please post screenshots of gparted view of BOTH your disks. Also, do you have a Windows installation/repair CD/DVD? Cheers, Al

Comment: I do not have a windows repair/installation disk.  How can I post a screenshot?

Comment: Also I tried the information in this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and it will now boot into the grub menu, but only ubuntu is showing.

Comment: Sorry newuser: read the answer below: you need the Windows 10 Recovery disk to recover the windows MBR.  When doing things manually, better to take a full system backup first...  **:-(**

Comment: Just a  quick update.  I was able to rebuild the partition table with testdisk.  I'm now able to see the partitions on the disk in ubuntu.  It's still showing as not recognized in the BIOS though and is not trying to boot windows so I'll see what I can do with the MBR next. Any tips? Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When manually installing partitions, one of the steps is to also manually set the boot record...  If you didn't move the boot record to your SSD manually and left it the way it was, it overwrote the boot record on your primary drive.

If that drive contained something else (e.g. Windows 10) Windows won't be able to boot any more.

To solve this look over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader) as Windows is off-topic here.

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**